# How to pass a Break in a string variable in Typescrip/Angular and bind that string to <p> tag

Tags: html, angular, string, typescript

Let's say I have a variable in my typescript class called `description` and the type is `String`.

**And what I want is that I can pass HTML elements inside the description variable, specifically I want to be able to pass new lines. And that I can add the string tag to a paragraph tag and that is aplies the html inside the string**

I tried to put `'\n'` and also `<br>` in the description variable but I did not get the result I wanted. All the text was still outputted in one line.
[image]

This is the html btw:
[image: this is the html]

Result: [image]

**Is it Possible what I want and know. If not what could be better alternatives for this problem.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind to the `innerHtml` of the element, which should render your `<br>` tags:

```
<p [innerHtml]="description"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this which all allows you to pass in html in your variable https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b